# onload not getting called for object element

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have an object element in my html with a blank data attribute which is then set later upon a ajax response. Now I want to get the event when the DOM for the object content document is ready.

If I use onload on the object element it works in firefox and Opera but it does not work in Webkit based browser.

How can I have the onload event trigger in all the browsers

The html looks like this

```
<object id="myobj" data="" />
```

the javascript that works in FF but not in WebKit is

```
 e = doc.getElementById("myobj")
 e.onload = function(){}
 e.data="http://myurl"
```

Comment: Is using a library such as jQuery out of the question?

Comment: no, if jquery takes care of it I will be happy to use it

Comment: @Raks Could you provide a live demo?

Comment: I think I might have misunderstood your question... are you talking about page load or when the myobj element is loaded?

Answer (score 0):

In theory `onload` is [strictly for the `body` element](http://www.w3.org/2007/07/xhtml-basic-ref.html#attr_onload). If certain browsers allow it for other elements more power to them but it's not required.

Also: is your semicolon key broken?

Comment: Not just the body element. The load event fires on images, iframes, scripts, stylesheets, video/audio elements, ...

Comment: XHTML 1.1 Basic isn't exactly a comprehensive guide to standardised markup languages supported by browsers

Answer (score 0):

I've tried the code with Safari 5.0.2 and it worked.  You can verify by alerting after assigning the new value.  When you view the source it isn't there but the newly assigned value can be accessed from any method.

```
 e.data="http://myurl";
 alert(e.data);
```

ie:

```
function doThis() {
 var data = document.getElementById("myobj");
 alert('retrieved from a method ' + data.data);         
 }
```

Answer (score -3):

In jQuery, to call something on page load, all you have to do is use:

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
    //your code here to populate your object's data attributes
});
```

This will work in all browsers.

Comment: That fires on DOM ready, **not** page load … and the question is about `<object>` load, not page load anyway.

Comment: If you'd read above before marking down, you would have seen where I realized I might have misunderstood the question and was trying to clarify